# SQL Error: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

Like any other question I am facing problem whenever I am trying to UPDATE my DataGridView through UI. Here is the error I am getting:

SQLException was unhandled. String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Now here is my column list which I am trying to update:

1. ShipTrackingNumber (nvarchar(100), null)
2. ShipMethodTransmitted (nvarchar(50), null)
3. DateShipTransmitProcessed (datetime, null)
4. ShipmentProcessedBy (nvarchar(50), null)
5. Critical (nchar(1), null)
6. ShipTransmitStatus (nvarchar(50), null)

Now you got the columns listings and their properties. Here is the code which updates these columns:

```
public void SaveDataSet(DataTable table)
{

  foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
  {

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(
    "update dbo.JobStatus SET ShipTrackingNumber = '@trackingNumber', ShipMethodTransmitted = '@TransmitMethod', DateShipTransmitProcessed = @DateProcessed, ShipmentProcessedBy = '@ProcessedBy', Critical = '@Critical', ShipTransmitStatus = '@TransmitStatus' WHERE JobTableId = @JobTableId ", _mySqlConnec);


    //Updated the parameters to the SQL Query!
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@trackingNumber", row["Tracking#"].ToString()));
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TransmitMethod", row["TransmitMethod"].ToString()));
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateProcessed", row["DateProcessed"]));
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProcessedBy", row["ProcesssedBy"].ToString()));
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Critical", row["Critical"].ToString()));
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TransmitStatus", row["Status"].ToString()));
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@JobTableId", row["JobID"].ToString()));

    cmd2.Connection = _mySqlConnec;
    _mySqlConnec.Open();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    _mySqlConnec.Close();
  } 
}
```

}

Can anyone please help me in this regard. Thank You!

Comment: What's in row["Critical"]? Your error is correct if it's more than a single character.

Comment: Please update your code to use Using statements.  As it stands you run the very real possibility of overloading your connection pool and getting fun errors like can't create connection to sql server...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to have quotes around any of your paramters.

change your sql to:

```
update dbo.JobStatus SET ShipTrackingNumber = @trackingNumber, 
ShipMethodTransmitted = @TransmitMethod, 
DateShipTransmitProcessed = @DateProcessed, 
ShipmentProcessedBy = @ProcessedBy, Critical = @Critical, 
ShipTransmitStatus = @TransmitStatus WHERE JobTableId = @JobTableId
```

It is basically trying to insert the string "@Critical" into a nchar(1) which is causing the truncation error.

Comment: I thought you beat me :)  just seen yours after i edited the formatting

Comment: phttt, I beat you both by 8 minutes, mine was just a comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

One of the values you are passing in is longer than the column you are trying to insert into.  If you can provide us with a sample of row data that errors out we can tell you which one.

For example if you tried to update your `critical` column with the value "yes" you would see the above error.

Comment: Do you know exactly what row in your data grid is causing the error?

Comment: Tracking Number: 5545254, TransmitMethod: FedEX, DateProcessed: 1/1/1900, ProcessedBy: ME, Critical: Y, Status: ""

Comment: I'm not a mySQL person, do you have to quote the variables for nvarchar columns in the update statement, you don't have quotes around the datetime one?

Comment: Yes, because DateTime one does not require (I GUESS) :-|